# Is there something in an error that could trigger an "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference"?

Tags: go, runtime-error

I had an application where I was occasionally crashing with a:

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x122e64a]

The trace kept leading to a return statement that returned a struct and errors.New("Some text for debugging: " + err.Error())

The struct didn't seem to have anything that would be dereferencing a pointer, but I restructured the function so it used a pass by reference and didn't need to return the function; it only returned the errors.New(). The panic still happened.

I went through the function and changed it so it returned just the err, no errors.New() string plus err.Error(). Now I can't seem to induce the panic anymore...

So the question: is there something about errors.New() using the err.Error() concatenated to a string that would cause that type of panic in a return statement?

EDIT: Adding a snippet of code that triggered the occasional panic:

```
strctStats.intThreadPool80ConnectionCount, err = strconv.ParseInt(strctStats.strThreadPool80ConnectionCount, 10, 64)
if err != nil {
    // Exit external application; send the closing sequences
    tmPause := time.NewTimer(time.Second * 2)
    <-tmPause.C
    stdIn.Write([]byte("close\n"))
    tmPause = time.NewTimer(time.Second * 2)
    <-tmPause.C
    stdIn.Write([]byte("quit\n"))
    return errors.New("Could not parse integer: " + err.Error())
}
```

EDIT 2: @lmars requested a stack trace. This is what is dumped to the console. Not sure how it helps (could you explain what it tells beyond the function stack and line numbers where the error/calls originated? I'm new to working on some of these traces)

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x20 pc=0x122e64a]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.JMXCheck(0xc42012c000, 0x1a, 0xc420018084, 0x2e, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)

/Users/bsilver/go/src/nagios_tomcat_threadinfo/nagios_tomcat_threadinfo.go:590 +0x38ca
main.main()
/Users/bsilver/go/src/nagios_tomcat_threadinfo/nagios_tomcat_threadinfo.go:146 +0x3cc
```

Comment: if `err` is nil, then `err.Error` is a `nil pointer dereference`. It's possible that `err.Error()` dereferences a nil pointer somewhere else, but we can't tell without the stack trace or context around where you're calling it.

Comment: did you maybe do `if err == nil { return errors.New("Some text for debugging: " + err.Error()) }` instead of `if err != nil`?

Comment: @JimB - My first impulse was thinking err was nil, but the return was in an "if err != nil" block.

Comment: @dave - I triple checked...all the if err's are != checks. That's part of why this was so strange to me!

Comment: @BartSilverstrim: then you may have either introduced a dynamic type in the interface (see https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error), or the error value itself has a nil pointer that is hit during `Error()`. Either way we need a full example and the actual output you see.

Comment: @JimB I tried adding a snippet of what triggered the panic. The trace just points to the return line and the calling line number for that function.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim: you're not showing how `err` is declared and used up to that point. I'm guessing it has had a typed `nil` assigned to it at some point. Use `fmt.Errof` or stick a `fmt.Printf` in there and see what the actual value of `err` is. (BTW, there is a `time.Sleep` function)

Comment: I agree with JimB. There are only two possibilities. err is not type of Error interface (check err.(*ErrorType)) or err value changes somewhere outside before return is reached..

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Just for the record you can call methods on `nil` pointers in Go (in general) and it does not necessarily panics (or give an error).

Comment: @lmars Added a crash trace.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example,

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
)

func f() error {
    err := error(nil)
    return errors.New("Could not parse integer: " + err.Error())
}

func main() {
    f()
}
```

Output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x44ecd6]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.f(0xc420022070, 0xc420022070)
    /home/peter/gopath/src/so/error.go:9 +0x26
main.main()
    /home/peter/gopath/src/so/error.go:13 +0x22
exit status 2
```

See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).